# Does new Date().getTime() in Browser Javascript always yield UTC?

Tags: javascript, time

Can I rely on Date().getTime() always giving the milliseconds in UTC, or is it dependent on the user's browser settings/location/system timezone?

Comment: It's worth reading the relevant part of ECMA-262: [*21.4.1.1 Time Values and Time Range*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range).

Answer (score 4):

`Date().getTime()` always returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch, which all of the timezones experienced at the same time.  Dates in that format have no timezone, which is only used during display.

For example, for `var date = 0`:

```
00:00:00 01/01/70 +00:00
01:00:00 01/01/70 +01:00
02:00:00 01/01/70 +02:00
17:00:00 12/31/69 -07:00
20:00:00 12/31/69 -04:00
```

All of these times are the same!  Just different displayed strings for the same moment in time: 0.

Answer (score 1):

The MDN page for Date (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) says yes.

> The getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.

The ECMAScript 1 spec from 1997 (linked in the mdn page) also seems to suggest a UTC value.

Comment: I wish I had refreshed the page and looked at @TbWill4321's answer before posting.